# Merging Points and Polygons

Tags: qgis, polygon

I'm very new to using QGIS and I'm struggling with one aspect of creating a set of polygons by land tenure.

Essentially I have four sets of landowners each with parcels of land - I have converted the addresses of each holding into points on a map. I have a cadastre/lot boundary layer (Polygon) as well. I was hoping to convert the points into their corresponding lout boundary polygons which they fall within for better optics.

The only method I've been able to do successfully is selecting the polygon lots individually and exporting as a new layer, this isn't ideal with such a large dataset.

Comment: Have a look at spatial selection in QGIS https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/performing_spatial_queries.html. When you say convert the points to polygons are you wanting the attributes of the points to be transferred to the land parcel polygons?  If so you want a spatial join https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_spatial_joins.html

Comment: Ideally I would like all polygons (Cadastre lot boundaries) where a point (Address) sits within it, to be selected so that I can create a new polygon layer of all property boundaries owned by XYZ - I haven't had much success with spatial join, I'll take another look

Comment: Hi Luca, can you give us a data-sample of your vector files? You can extract a little selection of polygons and points. You can provide a download-link with files as a comment in this thread.